# Strange call order of destructors

Tags: c++

I know that when I pass an object to a function which has a parameter without a reference the copy-constructor is called;also when I return an object in a function.The problem appears when I try to assign the function to a local object.The order of the destructors is not the usual one and I can't figure out why.

```
class myClass{
  int x;
  static int y;
  string name;
public:
    myClass(int i=10):x(i){ y++;cout<<"constr "<<y<<"\n"; name= "constr" +to_string(y) +'\n';}
    myClass(const myClass&ob){y++; x= ob.x; cout<<"copy-c "<<y<<" \n"; name= "copy-c" +to_string(y) +'\n';}
    ~myClass(){cout<<"destr " +name +'\n'; }

};
int myClass::y;
```

```
myClass f(myClass ob)
{
    return ob;
}
//main
myClass ob;
myClass s=f(ob);
```

Output: 
constr 1 
copy-c 2
copy-c 3
destr copy-c2
destr copy-c3
destr constr1

Comment: BTW, newlines don't slow down your program or expand your executable size.  When used judiciously, they make your code easier to read, which reduces injected defects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copy for the return value is [elided](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision); the return value of `f` is constructed directly in the space for `s`.

So, `constr 1` is the constructor for `ob`. `copy-c 2` is the temporary passed to `f`. `copy-c 3` is the constructor of the return value of `f`, which is also the constructor for `s`. At the semicolon, the temporary `copy-c 2` is destroyed. At the end of `main`, `s` and `ob` are destroyed, in this order.